# pointer arithmetic: *p++ and (*p)++ and more

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k=0;
    int* p=&k;
    printf("%d %d\n", p, k);
    *p++;
    printf("%d %d\n", p, k);
    (*p)++;
    printf("%d %d\n", p, k);
}
```

The code above prints this in Dev C++:

6422184 0

6422188 0

6412189 0 // p is increased 1 -> ???

The code above prints this in ideone.com:

368737692 0

368737696 0

368737696 0

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k=0;
    int* p=&k;
    int* t=p; // the only difference
    printf("%d %d\n", p, k);
    *p++;
    printf("%d %d\n", p, k);
    (*p)++;
    printf("%d %d\n", p, k);
}
```

The code above prints this in Dev C++:

6422180 0

6422184 0

6412184 0

I think (*p)++ increases the value of the variable p is pointing. So I believe the first code should print this in Dev C++:

6422184 0

6422188 0

6412188 0

Does the existence of int* t affect the way (*p)++ works? Or is this just a kind of undefined behavior? I am weak about pointer, please help!

Comment: Read Operator Precedence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `*p++;` is the same as: `*(p++);` which as `p` points to a single `int` is Undefined Behaviour.  Also as `p` was changed from it's original value the later `(*p)++;` is UB

Comment: You have plenty of *undefined behavior* in your code. First of all to print a ***`void*`*** you should use the `"%p"` format code to `printf`. Then you dereference a pointer that points to unallocated data, and *write* to that location.

Comment: @RichardCritten Not quite, `*p++;` is *roughly* equivalent to `*p; p++;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude your'e right.

Comment: @RichardCritten You can see what I am curious is why does `(*p)++` increase 1 of `p`. I think it is not a problem related to either `*p++` or `*(p++)`, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it is related.  Your using parenthesis makes the increment operation explicitely act on the value pointed to in `(*p)++`, whereas `*p++` is _implicitely_ equivalent to `*(p++)`.

Comment: @MichaelRoy I know that doing `(*p)++` after `*p++` is same to `*(&k+sizeof(int))++`, and what I pointed is doing `*p++` does not change the way `(*p)++` works.. I still don't know why `p` is increased after `(*p)++` only in Dev C++.

Comment: Oh.  I see what you are saying.  This obviously a bug in DevC++..  I've heard pretty bad things about DevC/DevC++.  Your example is a pretty good reason not to use it, as this is probably not the only bug in their compiler, this can only bring more confusion while you learn, and may lead to bad coding habits in the long run.  Have you considered using a less buggy compiler?

Comment: @MichaelRoy As I wrote, I tested the same code in ideone.com and got a satisfying result. Thanks for the explanation. Anyway, is this a common problem of GCC compilers, or just a problem of Dev C++?

Comment: I don't know.  You can quickly check and compare the assembly code generated by various compilers on the 'compiler explorer' site.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Why "bug"? UB (period).

Comment: My bad.  It is indeed an out of bounds error.

Comment: This line `int* t=p;` in the 2nd program has nothing to do with the outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with `p` pointing a `k`, a local scalar variable which is a single int.  You then increment `p`.  Since `k` is not an array, incrementing `p` results in an invalid pointer (not pointing at anything), and then dereferencing it results in undefined behavior.

Undefined Behavior means that *ANYTHING* might happen.  Anything.  While you might think that reading through the incremented pointer will just give you whatever happens to be in memory after `k`, there's no guarentee that will happen.  The compiler is free to produce code that actually changes the values of unrelated things (like the value of `p`) for what appears to be a simple read that can't change the value of anything.

In your case you actually modify (increment) the value pointed at be the invalid pointer, so its even more likely to cause strange and unpredictable results -- like munging the value of `p`

Comment: Since `p` is an int pointer,   wouldn't  `p++` will still move `p` by 4 bytes in 4 bytes integer platform?  So `p` will still point at somewhere.  I think dereferencing is the undefined behavior piece since the the data occupied by this new location can be any data type.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I've have finally understand your question and I think I have an explanation for it.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
            int k=0;
            int* p=&k; // p will point to k ( p -> k)

            printf("%d %d\n", p, k); // you will print p(k address) and k value

            *p++; // you increment p value so p NO LONGER points to k !!! 

            // p now holds another memory address (it is not related to k anymore)

            printf("%d %d\n", p, k); // you print the new p value and k value

            (*p)++; // here happens UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
            //you increment a value and you  know nothing about it 
            // is it an int ? is it a char ? is it p adress itself ? ... ???

            printf("%d %d\n", p, k); 
        }
```

I've tried your code on more compilers and I got different results(even on gcc under Ubuntu),too.
Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: He knows that p is it a int*.  Are you trying to point out that p is out of bounds?  It is out of bounds.  And yes this is probably where the issue comes from.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy yes .  I am saying that we don't know what type is **at that memory address**

Comment: My point: we know that p points to an integer.  It can only point to an int, and dereferencing it will always read/write an int at the address it contains. p being out of bounds does not and can not change the type of what p points to.  You'd be more correct by saying that If that address is out of bounds, this will bring about UB.